# Strong Tags inserted into Expression Engine

Tags: templates

Over the weekend, one of my sites has "strong" tags inserted everywhere.  I checked the templates, they are the same.  Any idea how they could have gotten in there?

Comment: If it isn't in the template, then a content editor must have added it to your channel fields. Or, a non-content editor found a way in and is screwing with you. It sounds like your site could be compromised; but I would bet it's a content editor messing about.

Comment: By content editor, you mean someone who has an account right? But how could they wrap strong tags around content if they didn't know what they were doing?  Or are they editing the core files?

Comment: What is producing these strong tags? Are they showing up inside of a `{exp:channel:entries}` loop?

Comment: There aren't strong tags anywhere in the templates.  They are on every part of the site.

Comment: Yea, so that sounds like you've been compromised somehow. Like I asked; are they showing up inside of a rendered template `{exp:channel:entries}` loop? I'm trying to determine if the strong tags are in your database or if there is something else going on.

Comment: It was entry in the content.  Not intentional.   Must not have been compromised, just operator error. Thanks!

Comment: Post an answer, I will give you credit!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some content wackery (just made that word up, I'm proud of myself!) going on. The content that gets rendered inside of a channel entries loop lives inside of a database table called `exp_channel_data`. When you call a channel entries loop, the rendered content comes from the database, and this is content that is generally editable by users who maintain your site.

Most likely what happened is someone went in to their control panel, and erroneously added `<strong>` tags in a bunch of places. Look over your channel entries to see if it's happened in more than one place. If you have a site with a lot of pages, you can search for instances of this tag with a MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.exp_channel_data 
    WHERE field_id_666 LIKE "%<strong>%";
```

Just change `field_id_#` to whatever your main content field id is (usually a field that gets called "Body" or "Main Content"), and you can do bigger searches to look for channel entries. If you have a small amount of entries, it's probably easiest to just use the Control Panel to investigate this data.